# Create a Procedure using a TClientDataset as a parameter

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I want to create a procedure in Delphi 2010.

This procedure will receive a TClientDataset 'cdTable1' parameter and an X Integer and it has to perform an action of close/open dataset:

`if cdTable1.Active then cdTable1.Close;`
`cdTable1.Params.ParamByName('MyParameter').AsString:=X;`
`cdTable1.Open;`

How can I define it and run it?

Comment: You create it just like any other procedure, and *run* (call) it like any other procedure. What specific part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Actually got trouble with parameters definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
procedure TForm1.MyProcName(cds : TClientDataSet; X : Integer);
begin
    if cds.Active then 
        cds.Close; 
    cds.Params.ParamByName('MyParameter').AsString := X; 
    cds.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender : TObject);
begin
    MyProcName(cdTabel1, 1234);
end;
```

In the interface section, where TForm1 is defined, you have to add:

```
public
    procedure MyProcName(cds : TClientDataSet; X : Integer);
```

If you are using a TDataModule, probably procedure MyProcName would find a nice place there instead of the form.

Comment: But there's no need to be bound to `TForm1`.

Comment: @AmigoJack There is no reason to not be bound to TForm1 either. Since I'm a fan of OOP, I almost always create methods of object instead of the old style pascal procedure.

Comment: Of course there are reasons: an instance of `TForm1` must exist to call that method, since it's not even static (and also from that perspective the procedure doesn't need to be bound to an instance).

Comment: @fpiette Forcing every routine into an unrelated object is **not** OOP.